# "bash: ./2: No such file or directory" how to fix this on ubuntu while trying to run a file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

So, i have been working on a reverse engineering challenge using gdb. I have this file which can be debugged using gdb but when i try running it with two arguments it shows no such file or directory even though it is there.
Details about the file:
It is a 32 bit file so i have installed the gdb-multiarch extension.
I have given it permission using chmod. But it is showing no such file or directory.
Any idea how to solve this.
When i give the two arguments, the file gives a output. That is what i want.

```
gani@gun-gani-PC:~/Downloads$ ./2 a b
bash: ./2: No such file or directory
```

But the file is present

```
2  3  4  5_alt  peda-session-2.txt  peda-session-3.txt
```

[The terminal Screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZxd0.png)

Comment: What do you get from `file ./2`?

Comment: Hey @Jester thanks for replying. 
I actually got the solution, as the file was a 32bit one, i had to install some packages
Ill add the answer here so that anyone else who comes across the same problem can see this solution.
If the file is a 32-bit executable, you need some libraries to execute it on a 64-bit architecture OS. To solve this error in Ubuntu, add the i386 architecture with the dpkg command, then install the necessary libraries.
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

Comment: Still, this does not really explain **that** error message, which you had received. bash should have reported then something like "cannot execute binary file". If your solution really solved the problem fully, I suggest that you post it as answer instead in a comment (it is OK to answer your own question), because this looks to me like a useful solution.

Comment: @user1934428: "No such file or directory" refers to the error encountered when trying to open the interpreter or library file named in the executable header, it is correct albeit confusing if you haven't seen this before.

Comment: @TomV : But wouldn't this apply only to text files having a `#!` line? From the screenshot - in particular the fact, that `gdb` was able to process the file - I concluded that it must be a binary executable.

Comment: @user1934428: no binary executables still contain string filenames that have to be opened, see the manual page for ld.so for example.

Answer (score 2):

> But it is showing no such file or directory

The problem is (was) that:

1. The binary is dynamically linked (use `readelf -Wl ./2` to observe that it has `PT_INTERP` pointing to `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`) and
2. With the 32-bit GLIBC missing, the interpreter was also missing.

When the kernel tries to start a new ELF executable, it performs the following steps:

1. `mmap` the file itself according to its `PT_LOAD` segments
2. IFF `PT_INTERP` segment is present, `mmaps` the interpreter (this is the step which was failing with `ENOENT` error) and
3. Passes control to the interpreter (which is responsible for `mmap`ing all required libraries and then running the executable itself).

It should now be clear why you were getting "no such file".

Here is a trivial repro:

```
$ echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -o /tmp/3 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/no/such/file
$ ls -l /tmp/3
-rwxr-x--- 1 user group 15976 Sep  6 19:55 /tmp/3
$ /tmp/3
-bash: /tmp/3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Should `ld-linix.so.2` not be `ld-linux.so.2`?